# Disable playback devices programmatically

Tags: windows, audio, disable

I would like to disable 2 specific playback devices. For example, right now SteelSeries Sonar - Media is enabled and I want it disabled same as: SteelSeries Sonar - Aux.
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGUpz.png)

I tried using powershell Get-PnpDevice and then | Disable-PnpDevice but it does not work. I also tried .\devcon.exe disable "@SWD\MMDEVAPI{0.0.0.00000000}.{E505A250-6F51-4E55-951B-16D5F4FAE9DE}" but it did not do the job either. Both Disable-PnpDevice and Devcon.exe reported that the device has been succesfully disabled but it was not and it was still selectable via audio icon in the tray:
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4TZZ.png)

I also tried disabling via registry but it did not work either.

My last option left which I found on the internet is: IPolicyConfig.SetEndpointVisibility. However, I am not a programmer and I have no idea how to use it. Could anyone help, please? I am using Windows 11 22H2.

Comment: Can you tell us the exact Powershell line you used for getting and disabling the device? This is just so we can verify if there weren't any errors in it.

Comment: There you go: Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "SteelSeries Sonar - Media (SteelSeries Sonar Virtual Audio Device)" | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false. I am sure the command is correct as I work with powershell on the daily basis.

Comment: And if you were to use just `Get-PnpDevice` - does it show your  "SteelSeries Sonar - Media (SteelSeries Sonar Virtual Audio Device)" ? If it does, what is its status?

Comment: Yes, of course it shows me the device. This is the command: Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "SteelSeries Sonar - Media (SteelSeries Sonar Virtual Audio Device)" | fl name,status

And this is the output:

name   : SteelSeries Sonar - Media (SteelSeries Sonar Virtual Audio Device)
status : OK

Comment: Perhaps you can achieve the disabling by using `DeviceId`, like it was done in [this case](https://superuser.com/questions/1682707/script-to-disable-enable-pnp-device-using-instanceids-but-the-ids-change-upo).

Comment: No, it does not work either.